# joomla 3 CCK extension

Tags: database-design, joomla, web

I am working on a new project with joomla 3 : 
a website for a sport center with about 20 teachers.
Each teacher has his own page and must be able to enter/edit specific data to present himself. Have a specific contact form, a specific weekly schedule for his classes.

The wesite must have a blog where each teacher can create articles with a link to  the teacher's profile.
There must be a general schedule for all the sport center's classes.
a calendar for specific events.

The teachers aren't realy "computer friendly" and so it needs to be very simple to edit and create the profiles. I tried K2/community builder but I can't manage the schedule/calendar entries.

I think a CCK would be the best option for this kind of project.
I tried out fabrik which seems to be very powerfull and I like the way I could manage databes entries and forms for profile editing. BUT I find it very difficult to manage the display of the database entries. Is there a plugin or other extension taht can manage that task?

I heard of sebold and will try it out ASAP.

I am looking for advice for this project, what extension would you use and why?

Regars

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Joomla! have no to much for select in this case.

We use Seblod a long time, because it very flexible, allow build a custom list and it only one (for my opinion) extension that can name "CCK".
But it a bit hardcoded so be ready to unexpected things, not a critical but can add some more work.

Before we also tried a k2, zoo and some other, it is good extensions if you will use it "as is", but if need to make the advanced customization there need a lot more work than with a seblod.

Comment: Thx for replying, I had a look at seblod 3, even if it seems to be a hard to handle extension it seems pretty intuitive. I also had a look at component creator witch seems to cover my needs even if I'll have a lot of coding to... I'm still searching